# Akka actor system design for distributed email mailboxes

Tags: akka, actor, akka-cluster

I would like to create distributed email mailboxes system based on Akka. When my app starts I would like to create all inbox actors and starts scheduler on them to receive mails on 10s intervals.
But there is a problem how to create these inbox actors? Is it possible to create actor on cluster or get reference to it if it exists? Actor name can be mailbox UUID in database, and only one actor with specific UUID can exists in cluster.

Most important question is how to create actor with uuid as name in cluster or get reference to it if it exists? I try this config:

```
actor {
    provider = "akka.cluster.ClusterActorRefProvider"
  }
  remote {
    enabled-transports = ["akka.remote.netty.tcp"]
    log-remote-lifecycle-events = on
    netty.tcp {
      hostname = "127.0.0.1"
      port = 2552
    }
  }

  cluster {
    seed-nodes = [
      "akka.tcp://mailbox@127.0.0.1:2552"]
}
```

And this code to create actor or get reference to it

```
def createActorIfNotExists(actorSystem: ActorSystem, name: String, props: Props)
                            (implicit ec: ExecutionContext): Unit = {
    implicit val timeout = Timeout(5 seconds)

    actorSystem.actorSelection(name).resolveOne() onComplete {
      case Success(actor) =>
        Logger.debug(s"Actor already created $name")
      case Failure(ex) =>
        Logger.debug(s"Creating actor $name")
        val actor = actorSystem.actorOf(props, name)
    }
  }
```

But above code create actor on local actor system instead on cluster (next node create own actor instead select existing).

For outbox I think about dispatcher actor too. Dispatcher will be cluster singleton and send messages to right actor childs. But it can be bottleneck?

Actor Path for singleton can be for example /users/mailboxes and for specific outbox /users/mailboxes/uuid

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like what you want to do matches Akka Cluster Sharding pretty nicely.

It allows you to address actors using an id and takes care of balancing actors across the cluster.

You can read more about it in the docs here:
http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.4/scala/cluster-sharding.html#cluster-sharding-scala

Comment: Thank you, this is what I need. Could you tell me is it possible to start all entities at system startup and schedule on them task to perdiodicaly downloads mails?

Comment: You'd somehow have to get a full set of all ids on startup, scheduling periodic downloads can be done using the actor system scheduler. You will need to think carefully about how your solution scales compared to the expected amount of male boxes though.